# Какать / kacken и Писать / pissen

Tags: этимология, обсценная-лексика

Можно ли отнести слова какать / kacken и писать / pissen к этимологически однокоренным?

Comment: Наш сайт посвящен русскому языку. Обсуждение его в связи с другими языками возможно, только если приведен весь материал, необходимый для работы с последними (их лингвистические законы, переводы иноязычных слов на русский...).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90688/discussion-between-aer-and-prostorech).